# How to reduce latency on AWS Lambda with python

Tags: redis, amazon-sqs, latency, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm trying to reduce latency of my Lambda python function, essentially queuing up the task and returning as fast as possible.

The lambda function receives a relatively small payload via the API gateway.

I've tried a few things, but all seem to result in ±200ms latency:

- pushing a message to SQS with the event data
- invoking another lambda function using boto3 `client.invoke` with [`InvocationType='Event'`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke) (which should invoke asynchronously)
- publishing an SNS message

Latency was measured after the lambda function was "warm". I also measured and compared with:

- returning without doing anything (<1ms)
- returning after pushing to redis on redislabs (~3-20ms)

A potential solution is to use redis as a queue instead of SQS, but I still wonder if I could improve latency for this use-case within the AWS toolset, or perhaps I did something wrong and shouldn't expect this kind of latency with SNS/SQS/Lambda invocation?

EDIT: here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/gingerlime/d6d2e89d10e9d7a0b056e84000f30bce) with the inline code used for invoking another lambda function. Execution time around 150ms ...

Comment: Are you creating the client object for the SDK within your handler function or at the module level?

Comment: @garnaat bingo!! It seems so obvious, no clue how I missed it... This dropped latency to ~10ms. Thanks so much!

Comment: ... actually, invoking another lambda function still takes much longer though, even if I initialize the client on the module. Not sure why. SQS is ~10ms; SNS is ~40ms ; Lambda invocation (even in `Event` mode) is still hovering around 150-250ms

Comment: That's weird.  Is that timing consistent?  You could still have startup costs even when calling async but only on the first call or after it's gone cold.

Comment: Indeed it seems weird. I tried about a dozen times and it seems quite consistent.

Comment: Just for kicks, you could goose up the memory allocated to the Lambda function.  This also increases the compute resources available although the exact relationship is unclear.

Comment: wat? ok, it did reduce latency to around 40-80ms if I crank it up from 128Mb to 1.51 gigawatts  - but there's nothing compute or memory-intensive about this lambda, it just gets the params and fires them off to another lambda :-/